# Ajax with CakePHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

i' m pretty new in using CakePHP and Javascript, i read many articles about request handling in cake, but i'm still confused, what i'm try to do is to send ajax request from my Javascript code to cakePHP and obtain some data in json format, i tried many ways to do this, but all the time I get simply html of page, instead of data i want to get, I have generated by default app controller class, as a url in Javascript request i use "http://localhost/pages/main" which is url of my view page where i have input controls, i wonder where in controller class should i put code responsible for handling request, and how to implement sending json response, thanks in advance

php code AppController class

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    // Note: These defaults are just to get started quickly with development
    // and should not be used in production. You should instead set "_serialize"
    // in each action as required.
    if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
        in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
    ) {
        $this->set('_serialize', true);

        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $data = ['data1', 'data2'];
            $this->set(compact('data'));
            $this->set('_serialize', ['data']);
        }
    }

    **javascript:**


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'localhost/pages/main.json';
    var data = {
        unit: 'someUnit',
        name: this.name
    };

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            console.log(xhr.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Could you show us your PHP and JS code?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you use [routing extension](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions)

`Router::extensions(['json']);`

then in your controller you can pass the [serialize data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) like this

```
$data = $this->Model->find();
$this->set(compact('data');
$this->set('_serialize', ['data']);
```

In your ajax request, just add .json extension to the url

Comment: I added to routes.php extension, and i added php and js code - it is same as in the post and it still does not work :/

Answer (score -1):

You can start here: [CakePHP official documentation for REST](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html)

Example:

```
// src/Controller/RecipesController.php
class RecipesController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $recipes = $this->Recipes->find('all');
        $this->set([
            'recipes' => $recipes,
            '_serialize' => ['recipes']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.